# Set AUTO_INCREMENT starting value in a InnoDB table to zero?

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb, auto-increment

Is there any to get the an AUTO_INCREMENT field of a InnoDB  to start counting from 0 not 1

```
CREATE TABLE `df_mainevent` (
  `idDf_MainEvent` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDf_MainEvent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL documentation:

> If a user specifies NULL or 0 for the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column in an INSERT,
>   InnoDB treats the row as if the value
>   had not been specified and generates a
>   new value for it.

So it means that 0 is a 'special' value which is similar to NULL. Even when you use AUTO_INCREMENT = 0 is will set the initial value to 1.

> Beginning with MySQL 5.0.3, InnoDB
>   supports the AUTO_INCREMENT = N table
>   option in CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE
>   statements, to set the initial counter
>   value or alter the current counter
>   value. The effect of this option is
>   canceled by a server restart, for
>   reasons discussed earlier in this
>   section.

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading, as MySQL _does_ allow zeros in `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578518/set-auto-increment-starting-value-in-a-innodb-table-to-zero/16291136#16291136 for the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE `df_mainevent` (
  `idDf_MainEvent` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDf_MainEvent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

works with MySQL >= 5.0.3.

**EDIT:**

Just noticed that MySQL in general does not like auto-increment values equal to `0` - that's independent from the used storage engine. MySQL just uses `1` as the first auto-increment value. So to answer the question: **NO** that's not possible but it does not depend on the storage engine.

Answer (score 2):

This works in both InnoDB and MyISAM, and the second insert is a `1` not a `2`:

```
CREATE TABLE ex1 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=MyISAM;

SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

INSERT INTO ex1 SET id=0;
INSERT INTO ex1 SET id=NULL;

SELECT * FROM ex1;

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  1 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

CREATE TABLE ex2 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SET sql_mode='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

INSERT INTO ex2 SET id=0;
INSERT INTO ex2 SET id=NULL;

SELECT * FROM ex2;

+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  1 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Daren Schwenke's technique works. To bad that the next record inserted will be 2.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` (
`ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY( `ID` )
) ENGINE=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table_name` (`Name`) VALUES ('Record0?');
UPDATE `table_name` SET `ID`=0 WHERE `ID`=1;
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`Name`) VALUES ('Record1?');
SELECT * FROM `table_name`;

ID     Name
0      Record0?
2      Record1?
```

This isn't a big deal its just annoying.

Tim

Comment: Just do another ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; after the first insert.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to have autoincrement start at 0, but starting at 1 and then setting it to 0 via an UPDATE works fine.

I commonly use this trick to detect deletes in a table.

On update of any row, I set that row's last update time.

On deletes, I set the last update time of row 0.